# Get UIImage from an array of points

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have an array of CGPoint objects. The array represents a line. Element 0 is the starting point of this line. Element 1 is the next point and so on. I know what color and thickness in pixels I want to give to the line. I want to end up with a UIImage that contains this line. I am thinking of doing something like this:

```
// Get graphics context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 1.0)

// Draw line
let line = UIBezierPath()
if let startingPoint = points.firstObject as? CGPoint {
    line.moveToPoint(startingPoint)
}

for point in points { // Would I need to ignore the first point?
    if let point = point as? CGPoint {
        line.addLineToPoint(point)
    }
}

// Obtain image and save to file

// End graphics context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Would this work? Is there a standard or better way to do this? Feel free to answer in Objective C :)

Comment: Where does `points` come from?  How come it's not a `[CGPoint]` (you have to `if let` into `CGPoint`)?

Comment: points is an NSArray returned from a closed source framework written in obj-C. Should I convert to [CGPoint] first? What are the advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `UIBezierPath`, you have to loop through the points. But you probably want to *move* to the first point, and then *append* the subsequent points:

```
line.moveToPoint(points.first!) // assumes points is never empty, otherwise use an if let or other guard
for point in points[1..<points.count] { // skip the first one
    line.addLineToPoint(point)
}
```

Or you could use a generator:

```
var stream = points.generate()
line.moveToPoint(stream.next()!) // assumes points is never empty, otherwise use an if let or other guard
while let point = stream.next() {
    line.addLineToPoint(point)
}
```

One advantage of @John Tracid 's approach is that you can use `CGContextRef` functions. While `UIBezierPath` does not have a convenience function for constructing an N segment polyline from an N+1 array of points, `CGContextRef` does:

```
CGContextAddLines(bitmap, points, points.count) // might need a magical cast here
```

Answer (score 1):

If your drawing is complex and your expect that it will be time consuming then better to use bitmap and draw at background thread like this:

```
CGFloat imageWidth = 100;
CGFloat imageHeight = 100;

// create bitmat with prarameters you need
CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(...);
CGContextBeginPath(bitmap);

// your drawing here

// result image
CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

// Clean up
CGContextRelease(bitmap);
CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
```

Comment: Makes sense. And what do you think about my Draw Line code?

Comment: @JonSetting you could use CoreGraphics functions instead of `UIBezierPath` because it is just a wrapper. Also if you don't need curve then better to use straight lines.